# Text should be shown in two lines

Tags: html, css

I need to show title in two line.
Like it shown in below image.Second Item is fine but first Item is coming is single line that I dont want

```css
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
    width: 120px !important;
    top: 80px !important;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed">Group Members</div>
<div class="ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed">Temp Document Library</div>
```

Comment: And .... ? Have you tried something ? Reduce the width of the element ? Force the line break with `br` ? Which Kind of solution do you expect?

Comment: I know you want to refrain from using these in general, but why don't you just use a `<br>` between Team and Members.

Comment: CSS  won't help here. both div do have the same class but different text. you need to add a class or a simple br . Javascript could help to sort it out ...

Comment: @DaniP if I try to reduce width... in second element Library will go down that I dont want.

Comment: That's why I comment **Have you tried something ? ... Which Kind of solution do you expect?**

Comment: May be a silly question just wanted to know, does the class need to be same ?

Comment: @SarojSasmal yeah both class will be same

Comment: You have set the `width:120px !important` if it exceeds that width text will be hidden (https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/6ce9ym4n/1/), if you want that it's fine else here is a thought you cdan use `word-wrap: break-word` with a max width .(https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/6ce9ym4n/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the width:

```
width: 80px !important;
```

is it that important?

If you don't whant to change the width, you could put a `<br/>` in the middle of the title.

```
<div class="ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed">Group <br/> Members</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can achieve it although leo's answer is simple and elegant.

```
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
    top: 80px !important;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: visible; 
    word-wrap: break-word; // word break with overflow display
    max-width: 120px;
}
```

please check out the link.

https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/6ce9ym4n/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by changing the elements width.
But if you don't want to mess with the width, then simple solution is to use `padding` and `box-sizing: border-box` properties.

Like this:

```css
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
    width: 120px !important;
    top: 80px !important;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed">Team Members</div>
<div class="ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed">Draft Document Library</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want "Team Members" to be on two lines? But keep everything else?

I would wrap those words in a wrapper that way you don't have to repeat that class on ever menu item. I don't know how much you can customize the html but this might work better for you:

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-container">
    <span class="two-line-title">Team Members</span>
    <span>Draft Document Library</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title-container {
    width: 120px !important;
    top: 80px !important;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: top 0.5 ease-out; 
}

.title-container span {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.two-line-title {
    width: 70px !important;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/ryRRRv